# Getting employee compensation records using PL/SQL function

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am new to stackoverflow and new to PL/SQL. I am working on some PL/SQL questions and trying to figure this out.

Basically, I want to create a PL/SQL function called GET_ANNUAL_INCOME to return the annual compensation for a specified employee, computed from an employee’s monthly salary and commission based on this formula:

```
  annual_ income = salary*12 +(commission_pct*salary*12)
```

The GET_ANNUAL_COMPN function should accept one paramter – employee id and use an appropriate query against er.employees tbl to calculate the annual income for that employee. I want to use the above formula in the select statement to get annual salary

I have created the function - (Is this correct?)

```
CREATE FUNCTION GET_ANNUAL_INCOME (iEmpId IN INT) 
RETURN FLOAT 
IS annual_income FLOAT;

BEGIN  

SELECT salary *12 +(commission_pct*salary*12) 
INTO annual_income
FROM Employee 
WHERE EmpId = iEmpId;
RETURN(annual_income);

END;
```

The second part of the question is what i an trying to figure out. Is there anyone who could help me with this or guide me.

Comment: What happens when you run the function?  You can edit your question to add this information.

Comment: Try naming the parameter empid, and prefixing it in SQL with the function name, so "WHERE EmpId = get_annual_income.EmpId". You will not have the inconvenience of all/some of your parameters prefixed with a letter.

Comment: Does the query give the correct results on its own? btw in PL/SQL `float` is just a [synonym for `number`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/predefined.htm#LNPLS2163), so you might as well use `number`; and you don't need brackets around `return` expressions (they'll just be ignored by the compiler), or for that matter BLOCK CAPITALS. And while I'm nitpicking, alignment is a useful technique for indicating the dependency structure of code in general.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine.

You can now query a specific empid

```
select GET_ANNUAL_INCOME(3) from dual;
```

or a set of empid

```
select GET_ANNUAL_INCOME(empid) from employee;
```

Comment: What if the empid is derived from a different table? How would that effect the code?

Comment: @Jasoncmzx, No effect. You can use it in any query you like, anywhere you like (SELECT,WHERE,ORDER BY etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Your function looks fine!!!

You can add an exception block if you need to, so that no unexpected errors are encountered at run time.

It can be done like

create or replace 
...

return..

exception
when others then
log_error_in_table
end;
/